# Auto generate mysqli_fetch_array column results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to auto-generate the mysqli_fetch_array column results, like:

```
$column_name=$rows["column_name"];
```

The values are stored in array '$lang_news_cols_arr', used as:

```
foreach($lang_news_cols_arr as $lang_news_col_name) { 
    $news_rows .= '$'.$lang_news_col.'=$rows["'.$lang_news_col.'"];';
}
```

$news_rows would then have the following result:

```
$column_name_1=$rows["column_name_1"];
$column_name_2=$rows["column_name_2"];
$column_name_3=$rows["column_name_3"];
etc...
```

And finally be used as:

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array ($query) ) {
    $news_rows;
}
```

I can't get the values to the $news_rows in the fetch array. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$news_rows is a string variable, php will not execute its contents as code without being explicitly instructed to do so. You could technically do this by calling the `eval()` function, but you really should not do this, since it introduces a huge security risk. `eval()` can execute any arbitrary php code, thus if a malicious user manages to inject their own code into $news_rows, then `eval()` will run that, too.

I would simply use an associative array to store the results, where the keys would be the column names.

Comment: Thank you! Good lesson there!